# How can I call a function from a class

Tags: c#, function, class, ping

I'm really confused. 
My Program.cs is as follows:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net.NetworkInformation;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace PingApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string filename = @"PingLog.csv";
            {
                using (var writer = new StreamWriter(filename, true))
                {

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then I have a class called WebSitePing.cs and this is where I have all of my code. This is my WebSitePing.cs class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net.NetworkInformation;

namespace PingApp
{
    public class WebSitePing
    {
        public void Ping()
        {
            var lstWebSites = new List<string>
            {
                "www.mearstransportation.com",
                "www.amazon.com",
                "www.ebay.com",
                "www.att.com",
                "www.verizon.com",
                "www.sprint.com",
                "www.centurylink.com",
                "www.yahoo.com"
            };
            foreach (string website in lstWebSites)
            {
                var roundTripTime = new List<string>();
                for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        var myPing = new Ping();
                        var reply = myPing.Send(website, 1000);
                        if (reply != null)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}", website, string.Join(" , ", roundTripTime));
                        }
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("ERROR: You have some TIMEOUT issue");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have to call in my WebSitePing.cs class into Program.cs so that I can create the PingLog.csv file and run the code in WebSitePing.cs and all of the results from my ping will be saved into the file which I created from Program.cs.
Can someone help me figure out how I can do this?

Comment: In your `Program.cs` file, you need to *instantiate* your `WebSitePing` class. Then, you will be able to use that instance to call your `Ping()` method.

Comment: alternatively make the method you're wanting to call static (it doesn't seem to rely on any instanced variables), but I agree that the better approach is probably just instantiating WebSitePing

Comment: Create a instance of the WebSitePing object by doing `var a = new WebSitePing()` in `Program.cs`. Then just call the method by doing `a.Ping()`.

Comment: I'm new to c#, can you give me an example, please?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using a method from one .cs file class in another .cs files class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11778642/using-a-method-from-one-cs-file-class-in-another-cs-files-class)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question was basically answered in the comments above, but here it is:

```
namespace PingApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var pinger = new WebSitePing();

            pinger.Ping();
        }
    }
}
```

In addition to that, you will need to move your `using` block into the `Ping()` method, rather than inside the `Program.cs` itself. That way instead of using `Console.WriteLine()`, you will append the output to your `StreamWriter` instead.

Alternatively, you can set the output of your `Console` like in @Enigmativity's answer, that will redirect your `Console.WriteLine()` calls to the `StreamWriter` instead of to the debugger console.

Comment: But in @Enigmativity's answer, its returning the websites but not the ping results, I don't think I'm going through all of the code from WebSitePing.cs

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
string filename = @"PingLog.csv";
{
    using (var writer = new StreamWriter(filename, true))
    {
        Console.SetOut(writer);
        var ping = new WebSitePing();
        ping.Ping();
    }
}
```

Not only do you have to create an instance of `WebSitePing` before you can call `.Ping()`, but you also have to set the output of the `Console` to your `writer`.

You would be better off making `Ping()` return `IEnumerable<string>` and then writing out those lines. It would be a cleaner program.

---

Your code for `WebSitePing` is a bit broken. Here's the simplest fix.

```
public class WebSitePing
{
    public void Ping()
    {
        var lstWebSites = new List<string>
            {
                "www.mearstransportation.com",
                "www.amazon.com",
                "www.ebay.com",
                "www.att.com",
                "www.verizon.com",
                "www.sprint.com",
                "www.centurylink.com",
                "www.yahoo.com"
            };
        foreach (string website in lstWebSites)
        {
            var roundTripTime = new List<long>();
            for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            {
                using (var myPing = new Ping())
                {
                    var reply = myPing.Send(website, 1000);
                    if (reply != null)
                    {
                        roundTripTime.Add(reply.RoundtripTime);
                    }
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}", website, String.Join(", ", roundTripTime));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If I try this I am getting the websites in the .csv file but not the ping results, how do I print the ping results?

Comment: @NewDev - Your code in `WebSitePing` isn't correct. It's not getting the time from the reply from the `.Send()` call.

Comment: Do you know how I can fix it? why is it incorrect? It was working when I had it all in one file.

Comment: @NewDev - I've added the fix.

Comment: That's perfect, thank you so much....I have been trying to do this all day- I'm trying to learn C#, any recommendations?

Comment: @NewDev - I would start answering questions here if you can, and when you get stuck look at the answers others give. Also, download LINQPad as a coding scratch pad. There are good little code snippits in there to learn from too.